# calculate how much percentage of the data is between two given points?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, quantile, percentile

I like to calculate how much percent of the data is between two given points?

let's say I have an array of floats:

```
a = np.arange(1, 2, 0.1)
a
>>> array([1.0 , 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9])
```

I would like to know how much percent of the data is between 1.2 and 1.7 from the above array
AND also
at what percent `1.2` is in the given array.

Something like quantile (25%, 50%, 75%) etc.

Comment: (a[(a>1.2)&(a<1.7)].size)/a.size

Comment: Thanks for the formula. Not able to get my hands on this formula from google.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy:

```
# percentage between 1.2 and 1.7:
np.mean((a>1.2) & (a<1.7)) * 100

# percentile of 1.2:
np.mean(a<1.2) * 100
```